# Python TypeError: iteration over non-sequence on simple list

Tags: python

```
import os

test = os.system("ls /etc/init.d/ | grep jboss- | grep -vw jboss-")
for row in test:
    print row
```

For some reason this gives the TypeError: iteration over non-sequence error on this.

When I do a print test without the for loop, it gives a list of the jboss instances, plus a "0" at the bottom..  The heck?

Comment: Read [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system).  `os.system` does not return any of the output of the program you run with it.

Comment: You are seeing a combination of the standard output from the pipeline, with the the actual value of `test` (0) at then end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`os.system()` returns the *exit code* of the process, *not* the result of the `grep` commands. This is always an integer. In the meantime, the output of the process itself is not redirected, so it writes to `stdout` directly (bypassing Python).

You cannot iterate over over an integer.

You should use the [`subprocess.check_output()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) instead if you wanted to retrieve the stdout output of the command.

In this case, you'd be better off using `os.listdir()` and code the whole search in Python instead:

```
for filename in os.listdir('/etc/init.d/'):
    if 'jboss-' in filename and not filename.startswith('jboss-'):
        print filename
```

I've interpreted the `grep -vw jboss-` command as filtering out filenames that *start* with `jboss`; adjust as needed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that `os.system` returns the exit code. If you want to capture the output, you can use [`subprocess.Popen`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen):

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen("ls", stdout=subprocess.PIPE),
out, err = p.communicate()
files = out.split('\n')
```

Also note that the use of the `subprocess` module is encouraged:

> The subprocess module provides more powerful facilities for spawning new processes and retrieving their results; using that module is preferable to using this [`os.system`] function.

If you do not have to resort to the shell, a pure python solution, as [@Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19168388/89391) suggests, seems preferable.